# Getting Terminal to do something else while running a localhost on it.

Tags: python, google-app-engine, terminal

How come I can't do anything else on terminal when It's running a localhost. Like I run a google app engine on it and make a new local host, I for example try to see what directory I'm in or even change directories, it doesn't respond to any of my requests? Thank you

Comment: Are you using it via gsutil?

Comment: No. It's fine, what I do now is open a new terminal window!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That instance of the terminal will be busy doing the thing you asked it to. But you can just open a new window or tab.